# mongodb native foreach does not return all documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I'm trying to update all database documents , but after try a simple use of foreach I can see that it's not returning all documents...

Perhaps mongo limit the number of documents for this function I don't know...
(I'm running this script from robomongo shell)

```
db.visitors.count();  // return 2219663
var count = 0;

db.visitors.find().addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout).forEach(function(visitor) {
 count++;
});

print('total:' +count);  // return only 44192 or 45575 it can change...
```

Comment: Is your collection sharded?

Comment: no simple collection, this is on mlab but I used mongodump to my local machine to check if its not due to their, but also in local the problem occur...

Comment: What do you get if you try `db.visitors.find().count()` ?

Answer (score 3):

OK I finally found the problem, it was from robomongo, I dont know why but when  I directly run the script in mongo shell it work..

Answer (score 0):

if the output value changes, I'm pretty sure the server exit on timeout, after doing some research I find that .addOptions() is [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.addOption/) in mongodb 3.2, try to use `db.collection.find({}).noCursorTimeout()`